# Why can I not use OrderBy() in this lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, lambda

How do I order the following? The orderBy doesnt recognise the x.Name.

```
var xRefsNames = db.CrossRefs.Where(x => pgNos.Contains(x.PG))
.Select(x => x.Name)
.Distinct()
.OrderBy(x=>x.Name);
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Your select is projecting a different object, probably a string based on the name. You want to just order by `x`.

```
var xRefsNames = db.CrossRefs.Where(x => pgNos.Contains(x.PG))
.Select(x => x.Name)
.Distinct()
.OrderBy(x=>x);
```

Comment: You could also order before the select, as both `Select` and `Distinct` maintain ordering, but it might be best to not rely on that.

Comment: @Servy, and probably cheaper to order the smaller set.

Comment: @PhilGan Marginally so, yes.  Given the asymptotic increase in sorting the size of the set would need to be quite large, and have a lot of duplicates, for it to really matter.